# Issues with Angular-CLI and Apache

Tags: apache, angular, proxy, angular-cli

I just ran the angular-cli setup for a new app.  I have Apache running which is serving a local API on port **80** at http://localhost/path/to/api.  Of course, `ng start` serves on port **4200** at http://localhost:4200.

I'm on Windows 10 if that is relevant.

So I researched proxying for Angular-cli and created `proxy.config.json`:

```
{
    "/api/": { //I've tried "/api", "/api", "/api/*", none worked
        "target" : {
            "host": "localhost",
            "protocol": "http:",
            "port": 80
        }, //also tried just straight "http://localhost" and "http://localhost:80"
        "secure" : false,
        "changeOrigin": false,
        "logLeverl" : "debug",
        "pathRewrite": {
            "^/api/clients/public/" : "/path/to/api/clients/public/"
        }
    }
}
```

And hooked it up to `npm start` via `package.json`.  I added the `"pathRewrite"` to test it on a specific path.

In the console, I get `ERROR Object { _body: "<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <h…", status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Object, type: 2, url: "http://localhost:4200/path/to/api/clients/public/" }` for the call `/api/clients/public/`

So from the URL I know the proxy config is working (pathRewrite is in effect) but the port is not changed.

I have tried every permutation of the config I've found on the internet and in the documentation.

Does anyone have an idea?

I also tried using a symlink into the Angular application folder but it is redirected to index.html, so if there is a way to exclude that path from the redirect, that works for me too.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a simple version of proxy-conf.json. Here's what I use:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

and run it with

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy-conf.json
```

This works for me when I use the Node.js server (runs on port 8000), and it also works fine with Java Spring Boot (the Tomcat server). My servers just return data. Why do you need path rewrite? Using proxy-conf.json is for dev environment. When you'll deploy the app bundles under Apache, you won't need this proxy.

Comment: I have tried this simple version, sadly does not work.  The pathRewrite was for debugging the issue.

Comment: What data your Apache server supposed to serve if there is no front end written in Angular?